# Data Structures in D3

Tags: d3.js

A group project of mine are struggling with a data structure, after having been told that it was initially wrong.

Alcohol consumption is the percentage of those who are on the mental health register in that particular city, so it should be a child element of mental health. To me, this looks right, but is producing no output in d3, only England, North England, Bradford City, Mental Health, and Alcohol Consumption produce an output, but not for Leeds. More data will be added, we just needed to get the structure correct.

```
var data = {
          "name": "England",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "North England",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "Bradford City",
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "name": "Mental Health",
                      "value": 1.22,
                      "children": [
                         {
                           "name": "Alcohol Consumption",
                           "value": 70.23,
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ],
                   "name": "Leeds",
                   "children": [
                    {
                      "name": "Mental Health",
                      "value": 1.22,
                      "children": [
                          {
                           "name": "Alcohol Consumption",
                           "value": 70.23,
                     }
                   ]
                 }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right structure:

```
var data = {
  "name": "England",
  "children": [{
    "name": "North England",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Bradford City",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Mental Health",
        "value": 1.22,
        "children": [{
          "name": "Alcohol Consumption",
          "value": 70.23,
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Leeds",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Mental Health",
        "value": 1.22,
        "children": [{
          "name": "Alcohol Consumption",
          "value": 70.23,
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
};
```

The children for `North England` should be a list of objects.

Comment: That worked perfectly, but i'm struggling to see the difference :/